# Add total count to grouped + summed data

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm struggling with a MongoDb query.

I have a query that makes group and count some fields, for example:

```
field_name | count
___________________
 
field1     | 10
field2     | 20
field3     | 30
```

And also I would like to add total count at the end to make it look like this:

```
field_name | count
___________________
 
field1     | 10
field2     | 20
field3     | 30
total      | 60
```

I understand how I can achieve it in SQL (either UNION or ROLLUP) although I can't find a way to do it in Mongo.

Here's my query just in case:

```
db.subscriptions.aggregate([
{$match: {isExpired: false}},
{$group: {_id: '$productId', count: {$sum: 1}}}
])
```

Comment: Here are some examples of [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html#examples).

Comment: @prasad_ Thanks for the link although I couldn't find an example that matches my question. Could you be more specific?

Comment: @qwertyqwerty is there always 3 fields or dynamic? you want to sum value for selected field?

Comment: @turivishal hello, the amount of fields is dynamic, as you can see in my example, I would like to add a field that will sum all values among the fields (in my example it's 60)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this with [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/)

`$facet` categorizes incoming documents. The approach I followed is, Get all document into one array (originalArr). You can use `$exists:true` for field_name or counts or both. It depends on you. Get the total count in another array (totalArr). Then `$concat` both array into one.

```
[
  {
    "$facet": {
      "originalArr": [
        {
          $match: {
            count: {
              "$exists": true
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$project": {
            _id: 0
          }
        }
      ],
      "totalArr": [
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "field_name": {
              "$first": "total"
            },
            "count": {
              $sum: "$count"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$project": {
            _id: 0
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      combined: {
        "$concatArrays": [
          "$originalArr",
          "$totalArr"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$combined"
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$combined"
    }
  }
]
```

Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ahwUttYPB6t)

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I need!